# How to use header() correctly in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

The problem I am encountering is with header('location: ') in php. I tried to insert it into a if statement, but is not working.

I am expecting to be redirected to example.com, instead it returns a 404 error. I've considered using other options, but I really want to try with header first.

```
<?php
include('login/dbcon.php');
include('login/session.php'); 

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$session_id'") or die('Error In Session');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($row) {

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        $newRedirectUrl = $_POST["redirectUrl"];
        file_put_contents("customRedirect.txt", $newRedirectUrl);
        echo "Redirect URL updated successfully!";
    }

    echo "
        <h1>Change Redirect URL</h1>
        <form method='POST'>
            <label for='redirectUrl'>New Redirect URL:</label><br>
            <input type='text' name='redirectUrl' id='redirectUrl'><br><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Update'>
        </form>
    ";
} else {
    $redirectUrl = "https://example.com";

    if (file_exists("customRedirect.txt")) {
        $redirectUrl = file_get_contents("customRedirect.txt");
    }
    header("Location: $redirectUrl");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: if example.com returns 404 after redirect, it's not a problem with header function, it's a problem with example.com or url.

Comment: i tried, it isn't a problem with the url

Comment: It is...because thats what a 404 means. The URL you're redirecting to doesn't exist.

Comment: Why are you putting `exit` towards the end of script?

Comment: to terminate the script

Answer (score 0):

According to notes on [PHP documentation on header function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you should be aware to do not send anything in output before the header call.

You can simply buffer the output to avoid that:

```
...
// your if code 
...
$redirectUrl = "https://example.com";
ob_start();
header("Location: $redirectUrl");
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```

Comment: True...but that isn't what's happening here